# Trouble installing react-addons-transition-group

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, reactjs

I am having trouble installing the "react-addons-transition-group" using npm. According to the react website:

> The addons have moved to separate packages as well: react-addons-clone-with-props, react-addons-create-fragment, react-addons-css-transition-group, react-addons-linked-state-mixin, react-addons-pure-render-mixin, react-addons-shallow-compare, react-addons-transition-group, and react-addons-update, plus ReactDOM.unstable_batchedUpdates in react-dom. - https://facebook.github.io/react/blog/2015/07/03/react-v0.14-beta-1.html

I have tried:

```
npm install react-addons-transition-group
npm install react-addons-css-transition-group
```

but I'm getting:

```
npm ERR! notarget No compatible version found: react-addons-transition-group@'*'
npm ERR! notarget Valid install targets:
npm ERR! notarget ["0.14.0-beta1","0.14.0-beta2","0.14.0-beta3","0.14.0-rc1"]
npm ERR! notarget 
npm ERR! notarget This is most likely not a problem with npm itself.
npm ERR! notarget In most cases you or one of your dependencies are requesting
npm ERR! notarget a package version that doesn't exist.
```

I am using:

```
"react": "^0.14.0-rc1",
"react-dom": "0.14.0-rc1"
```

so I am not sure why it is throwing the error. 0.14.0-rc1 is on the list of compatible versions.

My npm version is 2.11.3 and node 0.12.7

Any idea what could be causing this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This bug was fixed in `npm@2.13.1`. Basically, `semver@4.3.5` fixed a bug wherein pre-releases would satisfy the `*` semver range. When `npm@2.11.1` came out with this update, packages like `react-addons-transition-group`, which only have pre-releases for some reason, could no longer be installed by `npm` unless you explicitly told `npm` what version to install.

Issue tracker ticket is [npm/npm#8855](https://github.com/npm/npm/issues/8855). A guide for updating `npm` is available [here](https://github.com/npm/npm/wiki/Troubleshooting#try-the-latest-stable-version-of-npm).